# How can I put dynamically another number instead of zero?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want  put dynamically another number instead of zero in mongoose but i don't know how!

```js
displayCity: (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    provinceAndCity.findById({
        _id: id
    }).populate('city.0.limitation', 'title').then(city => {
        console.log(city)
        res.locals.cityData = city;
        next()
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`Error in find home city ${error}`);
    })
}
```

Comment: `'city.' + variable + '.limitation'`

Comment: `\`city.${var}.limitation\``

Comment: no! this way is not work. because it path json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I solved it this way  :D

```
   displayCity:(req,res,next)=>{
        let id = req.params.id;
        provinceAndCity.findById({_id:id}).populate({path:'city',populate:{path:'limitation'}}).then(city=>{
            console.log(city)
            res.locals.cityData=city;
            next()
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(`Error in find home city ${error}`);
        })
```